# solve puzzle with a tweet? javascript (fun challenge)

Tags: code-golf, puzzle-solver

the question is "complete this subtraction by replacing the asterisks with digits so the numbers 1-9 only appear once each"

```
 9**
-*4*
____
 **1
```

my code tries random numbers until it works, and displays the answer.  here is the entire html app.  I want one to fit in a tweet at 140 characters  (not counting  tags)

```
<script>
function r(){return Math.random()*9+1^0}
do{a=900+r()*10+r(),b=r()*100+40+r(),c=a-b,s=''+a+b+c
}while(c%10!=1||eval('for(i=0;i++<9;)if(s.indexOf(i)<0)1'))alert(s)
</script>
```

Is there any way to make this shorter, including with a different solution?

SOLVED!:
Thanks Peter, Shmiddty and copy, currently I have 91 chars!

```
for(x=1;++x<999;)for(y=1;y<x;)/(?!.*0|.*(.).*\1)9...4...1/.test(s=''+x+y+(x-y++))&&alert(s)
```

Comment: I'm thinking there must be a better way to check if it has each of the numbers 1-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JavaScript (<strike>118 110 102 96 95 99 98</strike> 93 chars)

```
for(x=1;x;x++)for(y=1;y<x;)/(?!.*0|.*(.).*\1)9...4...1/.test(s=''+x+y+(x-y++))&&alert(s,x=-1)
```

This will give the lexicographically smallest solution. Thanks to [copy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3428/copy) for 98->93.

You can enumerate all of them for 91 chars:

```
for(x=1;++x<999;)for(y=1;y<x;)/(?!.*0|.*(.).*\1)9...4...1/.test(s=''+x+y+(x-y++))&&alert(s)
```

Thanks to [Shmiddty](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7192/shmiddty) for pointing out a standard optimisation which slipped straight past me.

Allowing `0` as well, in <2.5 tweets, here's the analysis:

```
9ab-c4d=ef1; b-d in {1,-9}; 2nd => d=9 so bd in {32,65,76,87}, no carry. a-f in {4,*-6} so af in {62,73,*06,*28}. 9-c=e or *8-c=e so ce in
{27,36,63,72} or *{08,26,35,53,62,80}. af in {62,73} => no ce. af in {06,28} => ce in {35,53}; 06 => bd=87; 28 => bd=76. So four solutions:
927-346=581; 927-546=381; 908-347=561; 908-547=361
```

Removing `0` shrinks the analysis to fit in two tweets:

```
9ab-c4d=ef1; b-d in {1,-9}; 2nd => d=9 so bd in {32,65,76,87}, no carry. a-f in {4,*-6} so af in {62,73,*28}. 9-c=e or *8-c=e so ce in
{27,36,63,72} or *{26,35,53,62}. af in {62,73} => no ce. af=28 => ce in {35,53} => bd=76. So 927-346=581; 927-546=381.
```

Comment: `/re/.test` is a bit smaller than `.match`. You can also use `&&` instead of `if` then

Comment: 97!  superb.  regex's are so awesome. I need to work on them.

Comment: @copy - so in this case how would I use that syntax?

Comment: `for(x=0;++x<999;)...`

Comment: @Shmiddty yes! good catch.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing Yeah, I realized that and removed my comment.

Comment: @Peter Taylor - Thanks for the maths.  I'm new here, so I don't know if I'm supposed to follow certain cultural protocols to thank you for the analysis.  I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

## k (116 chars)

It's possible in k... Returns all possible solutions. (Count ignores unnecessary whitespace).

```
{a:"9",','[;"1"]i@&:6=#:'i:?:'{,/x,/:\:y}/7#,:"8765320";
 b:"I"$0N 3#/:a[;i],'"4",'a[;4+i:!4];
 b@&:b[;2]='(-).'b[;0 1]}
```

Comment: wow! never had heard of K. That's fantastic. If no one figures out a js solution I'll accept yours.